# What's wrong with this solution for Max Counters codility challenge

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

So I've been going through the tests on codility and got bit stuck with the "Max Counters" one (link https://codility.com/demo/take-sample-test/max_counters). My first, and obvious solution was the following one:

```
def solution(N, A):

    counters = N * [0];    

    for a in A:
        if 1 <= a <= N:
            counters[a - 1] += 1;
        elif a == N + 1:
            counters = N * [max(counters)];

    return counters
```

which works just fine, but takes too much time, due to the fact that each call to max counters fills an entire array.

So I came up with the following solution which seems to work ok for small inputs, but randomly provides incorrect results for medium and large ones.

```
def solution(N, A):

    counters = N * [0];
    current_max = 0;
    last_update = 0;

    for a in A:
        if 1 <= a <= N:
            counters[a - 1] += 1;

            if counters[a - 1] < last_update:
                counters[a - 1] = last_update + 1;

            if counters[a - 1] > current_max:
                current_max = counters[a - 1];

        elif a == N + 1:
            last_update = current_max;

    for i in xrange(len(counters)):
        if counters[i] < last_update:
            counters[i] = last_update;           

    return counters
```

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with it.

Edit: Result - http://codility.com/demo/results/demoQA7BVQ-NQT/

Comment: Unbounded to your problem but in python you do not need semi collon.

Comment: That's right. Haven't used python in a while.

Comment: What's the purpose of the last loop ?

Comment: I don't get it. The only way to put the same value to all the counter is to have A[K]=N+1 . 
Why comparing with last-update each element of the counter ?

Comment: It's to avoid having to update the whole array each loop and instead do it only once after the loop, for those counters which were not present in the input array. If you `print A, current_max, last_update` each loop you'll see what's going on.

Comment: E.g. input (3, [3,3,4,3]) will result in (0,0,1) -> (0,0,2) -> (0,0,2) -> (0,0,3). Last loop will make it (2,2,3) which is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is here:

```
counters[a - 1] += 1
if counters[a - 1] < last_update:
    counters[a - 1] = last_update + 1
```

what if `counters[a - 1]` was `last_update - 1`?

Comment: Of course. Moving the first line after `else` statement solves the problem.

Answer (score 21):

Check this one (python, get's 100 score):

The secret is not to update all the counters every time you get the instruction to bump them all up to a new minimum value.  This incurs an operation involving every counter on every occasion, and is the difference between a ~60% score and a 100% score.

Instead, avoid this hit by keeping track of the current minimum and maximum values; using and updating them for each counter you visit.

Then, after all the instructions are processed, because there may be counters which haven't been touched with their own personal update since the last update-all instruction, pass over the counters themselves and ensure they are at the minimum value.

```
def solution(N, A):
    res = [0] * N
    max_val = 0
    last_update = 0
    n1 = N+1
    for i in A:
        if i < n1:
            if res[i-1] < last_update:
                res[i-1] = last_update

            res[i-1]+=1

            if res[i-1] > max_val:
                max_val = res[i-1]
        else:
            last_update = max_val

    for i in xrange(len(res)):
        if res[i] < last_update:
            res[i] = last_update

    return res
```

http://codility.com/demo/results/demoF3AMPT-FVN/

Answer (score 10):

This is a modified version of @jacoor's solution with slightly more idiomatic python and variable names and if statement conditions more closely reflecting the problem description.

```
def fast_solution(N, A):
    counters = [0] * N
    max_counter = 0
    last_update = 0

    for K,X in enumerate(A): # O(M)
        if 1 <= X <= N:
            counters[X-1] = max(counters[X-1], last_update)
            counters[X-1] += 1
            max_counter = max(counters[X-1], max_counter)
        elif A[K] == (N + 1):
            last_update = max_counter

    for i in xrange(N): # O(N)
        counters[i] = max(counters[i], last_update)

    return counters
```

https://codility.com/demo/results/demo6KPS7K-87N/

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at my solution(written in C# though):

```cs
public static int[] solution(int N, int[] A)
    {
        // write your code in C# with .NET 2.0
        var counters = new int[N];
        var defaultValueToInitialize = 0;
        var maxElement = 0;


        //initializing the counters values, without increasing the N+1 actions
        foreach (var num in A)
        {
            if (num == N + 1)
            {
                defaultValueToInitialize = maxElement;
                counters = new int[N];
            }
            else
            {
                counters[num - 1]++;
                if (counters[num - 1] + defaultValueToInitialize > maxElement)
                    maxElement = counters[num - 1] + defaultValueToInitialize;
            }

        }

        //adding the increased default value to each cell

        for (int i = 0; i < counters.Length; i++)
        {
            counters[i] += defaultValueToInitialize;
        }

        return counters;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for posting but "counters = new int[N];" isn't necessary in the foreach loop is it? (EDIT: Oh I get it. That is necessary. It resets counters to all zeros.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider this 100/100 solution in Ruby:

```rb
# Algorithm:
#
# * Maintain a maximum value.
# * For each `increase(X)` command update respective counter.
# * For each `max_counter` command save the current max as `set_max` for later use.
# * Once the loop is over, make an adjustment pass to set all values less than `set_max` to `set_max`.
def solution(n, commands)
  max = set_max = 0
  counters = Array.new(n, 0)

  commands.each do |cmd|
    if cmd <= n
      # This is an `increase(X)` command.
      value = [counters[cmd - 1], set_max].max + 1
      counters[cmd - 1] = value
      max = [value, max].max
    else
      # This is a `max_counter` command.
      # Just update `set_max`.
      set_max = max
    end
  end

  # Finalize -- set counters less than `set_max` to `set_max`.
  counters.map! {|value| [value, set_max].max}

  # Result.
  counters
end

#--------------------------------------- Tests

def test
  sets = []
  sets << ["1", [1], 1, [1]]
  sets << ["sample", [3, 2, 2, 4, 2], 5, [3, 4, 4, 6, 1, 4, 4]]

  sets.each do |name, expected, n, commands|
    out = solution(n, commands)
    raise "FAILURE at test #{name.inspect}: #{out.inspect} != #{expected.inspect}" if out != expected
  end

  puts "SUCCESS: All tests passed"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript 100/100

```js
function solution(N, A) {
    var max = 0,
        offset = 0,
        counters = Array.apply(null, Array(N)).map(function () {return 0;});
        
    A.forEach(function (d) {
        if (d === N + 1) {
            offset = max;
        }
        else {
            counters[d-1] = Math.max(offset + 1, counters[d-1] + 1);
            max = Math.max(counters[d-1], max);
        }
    });
    
    counters.map(function (d, i) {
        if (d < offset) {
            counters[i] = offset;
        }
    });
    
    return counters;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### C# - a 100/100 solution

```cs
public int[] solution(int N, int[] A) {
    // write your code in C# 6.0 with .NET 4.5 (Mono)
    int[] counter = new int[N];
    int maxValue = 0;
    int minValue = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<A.Length;i++)
    {
        //less than or equal to length N
        if(A[i] <= N)
        {
            if(counter[A[i] - 1] < minValue)
            {
                counter[A[i] - 1] = minValue;
            }
            counter[A[i] - 1] += 1;
            if(counter[A[i] - 1] > maxValue)
            {
                maxValue = counter[A[i] - 1];
            }
        }
        else if(A[i] == N+1)
        {
            minValue = maxValue;
        }
    }
    for(int j=0;j<counter.Length;j++)
    {
        if(counter[j] < minValue)
        {
            counter[j] = minValue;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My python version only scores 66 points as it's a little too slow for the later tests.

```
def solution(N, A):
    counters = [0 for x in range(N)]
    for elem in A:
        if elem > N:
            cmax = max(counters)
            counters = [cmax for x in range(N)]
        else:
            counters[elem-1] += 1
    return counters
```

Answer (score 0):

100/100 solution in C

```c
struct Results 
solution(int N, int A[], int M) 
{
    struct Results result;
    int *cnts = calloc(N, sizeof(int));
    int i = 0, maxcnt = 0, j = 0, lastcnt = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        if (A[i] <= N && A[i] >= 1) {
            if (cnts[A[i] - 1] < lastcnt)
                cnts[A[i] - 1] = lastcnt + 1;
            else
                cnts[A[i] - 1] += 1;
            if (cnts[A[i] - 1] > maxcnt)
                maxcnt = cnts[A[i] - 1];
        }
        if (A[i] == N + 1)
                lastcnt = maxcnt;
    }
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            if (cnts[j] < lastcnt)
                cnts[j] = lastcnt;
    }
    result.C = cnts;
    result.L = N;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MaxCounters solution in C

```c
struct Results solution(int N, int A[], int M) {
    struct Results result;
    // write your code in C90
    int i,k=0,max_v=0;
    
    result.C =(int*)(malloc(N*sizeof(int)));
    result.L = N;   
    memset(result.C, 0, N*sizeof(int));  

    for(i=0;i<M;i++)
    {      
        if (A[i] > N)    
            max_v=k;
        else
        {
            if(result.C[A[i]-1] < max_v)
                result.C[A[i]-1]=max_v;
            
            result.C[A[i]-1]+=1; 
            
            if(result.C[A[i]-1] > k)
                k=result.C[A[i]-1];
        }   
    }

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        if(result.C[i] < max_v)
            result.C[i]=max_v;
    }
                    
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript 100/100

```js
function solution(N, A) {
    
    var j, len = A.length, lastBase = 0, max = 0, 
        counters = [], n1 = N+1;

    for(j=0; j<N; j+=1){
        counters[j]=0; //initArray
    }
    
    for(j=0; j < len; j+=1){
        if(A[j]<n1){
            if(counters[A[j]-1] < lastBase) {
                counters[A[j]-1] = lastBase;
            }
            counters[A[j]-1] += 1;
            if(max < counters[A[j]-1]) {
                max = counters[A[j]-1];
            }
        } else {
            lastBase = max;
        }
    }
    
    for(j=0; j<N; j+=1){
        if(counters[j] < lastBase) {
            counters[j] = lastBase;
        }
    }
    
    return counters;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java solution:

```java
public int[] solution(int N, int[] A) {
    // write your code in Java SE 8
    int[] counter = new int[N];
    int maxCounter = 0;
    int pos;
    int last_max=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        if (A[i] <= N) {
            pos = A[i];

            if (counter[pos - 1] < last_max)
                counter[pos - 1] = last_max;
            counter[pos - 1] += 1;

            if (maxCounter < counter[pos - 1])
                maxCounter = counter[pos - 1];
        }
        else{
            last_max=maxCounter;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < counter.length; i++) {
        if (counter[i] < last_max)
            counter[i] = last_max;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ 100/100

The key is to IGNORE the sample iteration in the problem, it will lead you to a O(m*n) time complexity solution.

```cpp
vector<int> solution(int N, vector<int> &A) {
// write your code in C++11

    vector<int> counters(N,0);
    
    int last_reset = 0, max_count = 0;
    
    for( unsigned int a=0; a < A.size(); ++a)
    {
         int current_int = A.at (a);
         
         if (current_int == (N+1))
         {
            last_reset = max_count;
         }
         else
         {
            unsigned int counter_index = current_int - 1;
             
            if ( counters.at (counter_index) < last_reset)
                counters.at (counter_index) = last_reset + 1;
            else
                ++counters.at (counter_index);
            if ( counters.at (counter_index) > max_count)
                max_count = counters.at (counter_index);
         }
            
    }
    for( unsigned int n=0; n < counters.size(); ++n)
    {
        if ( counters.at (n) < last_reset)
            counters.at (n) = last_reset;
    }
    return counters;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 100%

The following solution is simpler and easy to understand from the previous solutions in python where you can use set() to add a possible maximum number each time you find a new possible one. And after that when **A[i]** is equal to **N + 1** you update counters with the max number found in the set and reset it again since the old max would be smaller than the coming ones and not needed. So the line where we **clear** the set is very important to pass all performance tests

Detected time complexity is:
*O(N + M)*

```
def solution(N, A):
    
    counters = [0] * N
    max_numbers = set()
    
    for i in range(0, len(A)):

        if 1 <= A[i] <= N:

            index = A[i]-1
            counters[index] += 1
            max_numbers.add(counters[A[i]-1])

        elif A[i] == N + 1 and len(max_numbers) > 0:

            counters = [max(max_numbers)] * N
            max_numbers.clear()

    return counters
```

Answer (score 0):

100% solution with Python--what helped was to keep track of the max in each iteration instead of calculating it each time N+1 appeared

```
def solution(N, A):
    counters = [0] * N
    all_max = list(set(A))
    if len(all_max) == 1 and all_max[0] == N + 1:
        return counters

    the_max = 0
    for i in A:
        if i == N + 1:
            counters = [the_max] * N
        elif i > N + 1:
            continue
        else:
            counters[i-1] += 1
            if counters[i-1] > the_max:
                the_max = counters[i-1]
    return counters
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Python

```
from collections import Counter


def solution(N, A):
    stop = [i for i in range(len(A)) if A[i] > N]
    old = val = 0
    for s in stop:
        o = A[old:s]
        if o:
            val += max(Counter(o).values())
        old = s + 1
    c = [val] * N
    start = 0 if not stop else stop[-1] + 1
    for i in A[start:]:
        c[i-1] += 1
    return c
```

Answer (score -1):

here is the shortest solution in Python:

```
def solution(N, A):
    out = [0 for _ in range(N)]
    for ele in A:
        if ele<=N: out[ele-1] += 1
        else: out = [max(out) for i in range(len(out))]           
    return out
```

Comment: calling max() on out list each time reduces the time complexity.